# Putting ImageView Over ImageView in Layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have created an Android Application in that I want to put ImageView over ImageView.

How to make i possible.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want Circular `ImageView` above first one?

Comment: It's also possible through layer-list (XML )

Comment: I have posted my answer. see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created code for you:

#### See this is XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:arc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/holo_gray_light"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

    <yourpackage.MLRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/mLRoundedImageView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### MLRoundedImageView.java (put in src and update package name in XML):

```
public class MLRoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth();//, h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        //final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

May this will helpful to you.. Dont forget to Upvote If Helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use your layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 />
             <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Using RelativeLayout its not works, I have tried many times.

Comment: @SwetaSharma Look my answer again i have edited...

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can check this link too.

[How to achieve this UI in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680684/how-to-achieve-this-ui-in-android)