# Android move image in Loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I want to move my image with a For Loop or find info on doing such things

Here is some of my content_main.xml

`ffImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"                               android:id="@+id/imageView"                                         android:src="@drawable/pic"                                   android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"                                android:layout_marginStart="41dp"                              android:layout_marginTop="139dp"                                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"                                             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />`

So how can I do something like

```
int A;  
A = 41;
for ( int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) {
android:layout_marginLeft=A;  
A = A +1;
}
```

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: do you want to move your view with an animation or just move it by one step?

Comment: So the image glides across the screen not just one step

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView image;
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView image= new ImageView (this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);
layout.addView(image); 

int A;  
A = 41;
for ( int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) {
  image.setX(A);  
  A+=step;
  layout.invalidate();
}
```

But better change the name of layout from imageView to something else. Mixing names of instances and names of other classes is very bad style.

Good pieces of code are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437830/putting-imageview-over-imageview-in-layout).

Comment: Thank you Sir I've had a job finding such info ill have a go at what you suggested.

Comment: When I started to study Android, Stackoverflow and android.developers(this is for your theme: https://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html) were my best friends. And they remained.  And I am not a Sir. :-). Try also https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/ , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_image_effects.htm

Comment: I'm not having much luck - I'm really struggling with Android is there anyone who could go through this step by step with me.

Comment: Having real problems here are the results I'm getting https://s23.postimg.org/9d35qx1sr/Untitled.png                                               ImageView image;     Works on its own but the rest is giving me problems even just A=41 ???any help??

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I have not now running Android Studio on my PC. But there should be no problem... Have you declared the layout as RelativeLayout? It is VERY important.

Comment: https://developerlife.com/2008/08/05/android-animation-framework/ - tutorial straight for Android animation. Tutorials teach you step by step.

Comment: I got it working but there is no image movement - it just completes the loop or loops and then what ever the final value is, is were the image will be? i.e 91 - no movement while the loop takes place.

Comment: @MharlesCanson Then we should add .invalidate() to the layout to see the result. I am sorry, there are some cases when you need it and some when you don't. If won't help, use .setVisibility(View.GONE); .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @Gangnus what you're proposing doesn't seem to be a solution, the loop will run to the end and then, after returning, a single draw will be done

Comment: The problem is, that normally you put all changes of screen into onCreate() method. And at any refresh of the layout moves are done. That way to MAKE the layout change at will at any moment, is not the android way of thinking. Because of THAT it is so hard to realize.

Comment: @Gangnus I still don't understand why the for loop, if you want to just move the view there is no need for a loop

Comment: @lelloman As he asks to solve THIS task, this way of organization is more understandable to him. It is too difficult to change everything at once. So, I am trying to help him on his own way to enlightment. Everyone should have his own road.